# Activity vs Fragment in my case. I need practical example to fully understand this

Tags: android, android-fragments

In first I apologize for question that was answered here many times but I can't fully understand concept of activity vs fragment, and I need clarification on real example.

I'm in the middle of writing application that:

- Has hamburger menu and three activites there, I navigate between them
  like that:

  ```
  public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

  int id = item.getItemId();

  if (id == R.id.nav_searchForNew) {
      startActivity(new Intent(this, SearchActivity.class));
  } else if ...
  ```
- First activity lets user type TV show name and sends request to web
  api for basic information about the show, user can click button to
  subscribe the show. If he does the show is added to list.
- Second activity shows list of subscribed shows and lets user
  unsubscribe them.
- Third activity presents a list of upcomming episodes of subscribed
  shows.

So far I have only searchActivity written and I think that I should rewrite it as `Fragment` but I can't explain why.

Could I ask for a little clarification?

- What is the difference in this particular project?
- How different is sending list of subcribed shows between Activities
  and Fragments?

Comment: dddeee if my answer worked for you, please mark it as accepted.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given what you've explained of your project, you should use activities for all three of those functions.  A fragment is most useful when you plan to reuse a chunk of code in multiple places (ie. you want to use Fragment X in Activity A and in Activity B).  You don't seem to have a need for that.  Fragments are also useful if you want to have the ability to display different things on different size screens (on a phone, you could display one fragment per screen, but on a tablet, you could display all three fragments side by side).  That is a more complex undertaking and given that you are new at this, you should stick with activities for now.

For more on fragments, read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html